# Not able to upload pdf file to server

Tags: ios, xcode7, swift2

> "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set" error is
>   coming when i try to upload pdf to the server.

Sending :

```
    body.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";
     filename=\"file.pdf\";mimeType=\"application/pdf\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    body.appendData(fileData!)

    body.appendData("Content-Type: file/\(fileType)\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
```

Comment: Could you provide us with more info about your server setup, rest of code.. etc?

Comment: The issue got resolved when i first set the content-type then append file data. Dont know exactly what was the issue in appending first the data and then the content-type

Comment: For clarification @S.V, the _Content-Type_ header identifies to the server what kind of resource you are sending in your HTTP request. If we set this header to _application/pdf_, we are telling the server we are sending a data type of pdf. This way, the server can validate whether your request is correct or not.